# python pipeline does not execute imputer

Tags: python, pipeline, imputation

I analysing the gapminder dataset [1] using a pipeline in Python but for some reason the imputer does not replace the nan values. According to the documentation ("For missing values encoded as np.nan, use the string value “NaN”.") I should do it like below but the code crashes with "ValueError: Input contains NaN" in the line "gm_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)". But gm_cv was created based on the pipeline and the pipeline contains the imputation which should remove the nans. Why does this not work?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

fn = 'gapminder.csv' 

df = pd.read_csv(fn, delimiter=',')

# replace empty strings with numpy nans
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.replace(' ', np.nan, inplace=True)

targetVariable = 'lifeexpectancy'

X = df.drop([targetVariable, 'country'], axis=1).values
y = df[targetVariable]

steps = [('imputation', Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)),
         ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('elasticnet', ElasticNet())]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# Specify the hyperparameter space
parameters = {'elasticnet__l1_ratio': np.linspace(0,1,30)}

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.4, random_state=98)

# Create the GridSearchCrossValidation object
gm_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=3)

# Fit to the training set
gm_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

# results:
r2 = gm_cv.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Tuned ElasticNet Alpha: {}".format(gm_cv.best_params_))
print("Tuned ElasticNet R squared: {}".format(r2))
```

stack trace of full error:

```
python.exe pipline_and_classification_II.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipline_and_classification_II.py", line 55, in <module>
    gm_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 639, in fit
    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 458, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 250, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\coordinate_descent.py", line 709, in fit
    ensure_2d=False)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 453, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 44, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Update:
Debugging it slowly (without the pipeline) shows that the Imputer does not like 1d arrays (like y in my code above). When doing the nan-removing manually before with the code below it works.

```
y = np.array(y)
idx = np.argwhere(np.isnan(y))
y[idx] = np.nanmean(y)
```

But this defeats the purpose of the pipeline. Any ideas how to get this running without manual tinkering?

[1] http://makemeanalyst.com/download-and-learn-about-gapminder-dataset/

Comment: Post the full error (stack trace)?

Comment: Check `X.dtypes`, is it possible the `Imputer` requires variables to be numeric to use mean as a strategy? Also, try it without the pipeline and without the gridsearch first, it will be a lot simpler to debug.

Comment: In addition to what Dan commented, ElasticNet also requires input to be numeric, so if you have any text/categorical data you'll need to either discard or convert it first (look at OneHotEncoder for categorical features).

Comment: I am dropping the non numeric column ('country') - explicit type conversion (X = X.astype(float) and y = y.astype(float)) does not help. Will disentangle the pipeline and gridsearch then ...

Comment: Did you try reshaping `y` so something like `y.reshape(-1,1)`? You might have to cast `y` as a numpy array first. But also... missing values in your target variable... are you sure you should be imputing those? Maybe just drop those rows.

Comment: Actually you are right: I think droping these rows might be the better option!